# ¿Como generar un informe de los archivos que contienen un Winrar, utilizando c#?

Tags: c#, vscode

Buena tarde,

Desde hace ya un par de días estoy intentando generar un informe de los archivos que contiene un Winrar, el programa "Winrar" lo trae de manera nativa, pero lo necesito para un manejador de archivos, ya que mis usuarios solicitan que se les entregue el contenido de un directorio X.

Actualmente ya genero todo lo relacionado con archivos y carpetas normales, pero también debo agregar, al mismo archivo(.xls), el contenido de los .rar que estén en el directorio seleccionado.

El código que utilice para el excel es este:

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
                    app.Visible = false;
                    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Caso";
                    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Nombre";
                    ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Tipo";
                    ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Fecha Creación";
                    ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Ubicación";
                    ws.Cells[1, 6] = "Descripción";
                    ws.Cells[1, 7] = "Tamaño";
                    ws.Cells[1, 8] = "Usuario Crea";
                    ws.Cells[1, 9] = "Descarga";
                    int i = 2;
                    int j = 0;
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lv_4_detalle.Items)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i, 1] = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 2] = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 3] = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 4] = item.SubItems[3].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 5] = item.SubItems[4].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 6] = item.SubItems[5].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 7] = item.SubItems[6].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 8] = item.SubItems[7].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 9] = item.SubItems[8].Text;
                        i++;           
                        if ((".rar" == (ws.Cells[i, 3] = item.SubItems[2].Text)) || (".zip" == (ws.Cells[i, 3] = item.SubItems[2].Text)))
                        {
                            string ruta = item.SubItems[4].Text + "\\" + item.SubItems[1].Text;
                            MessageBox.Show(ruta);

                             System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                             proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                             proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
                             proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                             proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            //proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                             proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                             proc.Start();
                             proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"rar l " + ruta); //+">> E:\test"+ i +".csv");
                             proc.StandardInput.Flush();
                            //proc.StandardInput.Close();
                             proc.Close();  
                            //proc.WaitForExit(); 
                            //j++;
                            //MessageBox.Show("prueba " +j);
                        }
                    }
                    wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    app.Quit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Se ha exportado la informacion", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }                 
            }
        }
```

Este código funciona para crear el Excel, y el del rar funciona de manera local pero al momento de usarlo por medio del Server da un error de Acceso.

El reporte que genera winrar es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creen ustedes que exista alguna librería que me ayude a obtener la información que necesito.

Y el que necesito generar es muy similar.

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.